# Specify build order dependency

Tags: dependencies, gradle

I have module `A` and `B`. `B` is subproject of `A`.

In tests of module `A` I want use artifact from `B`.

How can I specify that `A.tests` should be performed after `B.build` without specifying any compile dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to declare that dependency in your buildscript of A:

```
tests.dependsOn(":B:build")
```

where tests is the Test task in A (do you mean 'test' here?)

cheers,
René